# I can't find the correct syntax for SELECT * FROM

Tags: python, mysql

It tells me that I have an error in the SQL syntax, but I also tried the simple version, only %s and although I enter the correct username and password (which are in the database) I can't log in (inccorect username or password). I also tried to replace (") with (') before SELECT.

> line 34, in login
> mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'", (username, password, ))

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = '%s' AND password = '%s'", (username, password, ))
        account = mycursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return render_template('index.html', msg = msg)
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)
```

Comment: I see only indentation problems in this code.

Answer (score 3):

Try the parameters without single quotes:

```
mycursor.execute("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = %s AND password = %s", (username, password))
```

Comment: I tried this and although the error disappears I still can't log in using the correct username and password

Comment: You may need to a bit of troubleshooting, for example message username and password just before executing the cursor it shows correctly, also you can try hardcoding these values in the query to make sure it returns something from the table.

Answer (score 0):

Beware of the indentation error, this line should be indented to be within the if statement scope. Btw, you can eliminate the quotations around %s, it can infer the type without putting the quotations.

Comment: I'm sorry, I made a mistake when I posted the code here. I checked in the application, the indentation is correct